# An arithmetic overflow error occurred while converting varchar to numeric data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008:

```
Create table ExTable1 
(
     Fcur varchar(50),
     Tcur varchar(50),
     Rt numeric(10,10)
)
```

I am trying to insert the data

```
Insert into [DB].[dbo].[ExTable1 ](Fcur, Tcur, Rt) 
values ('INR', 'EUR', 1)
```

Error I am getting is

> An arithmetic overflow error occurred while converting varchar to numeric data type.

When I change datatype of column `Rt` to `numeric(10,2)`, above mention query mentioned perfectly fine.

Data which I am going to insert in `Rt` column may have 10 digits after decimal.

How to fix this?

Basically I got this exception in C# code. So I tried executing the QueryString which was create in C# , directly in SQL server. I faced the same error.

Thanks

Comment: NUMERIC(10,10) will only hold values < 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric(10,10) will define a number consisting of decimals only...

Try it with `Numeric(11,10)` (one place before and 10 after the comma).

The first parameter defines the full width, the second the number of places behind the comma *within* the full width, [read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

decimal[ (p[ , s] )] and numeric[ (p[ , s] )]
Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

p (precision)
The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

s (scale)
The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.